# GTMOauth2 iOS refresh token

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth, token

i start a demo app from this exemple

https://github.com/Christian-Hansen/simple-oauth2

I can authenticate ti google and get back the AUTH object. 
If i NSLog the auth object i can see access_token, expire date and code but no refresh token..
Is it normal? Cause after some time i can't do request cause my access token si expired..
I have also added :

-(void)awakeFromNib method with auth.canAuthorize

I do something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @grobbins. The point is that i need to add these parameter on the request:

```
    viewController.signIn.additionalAuthorizationParameters = 
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:@"offline",@"force", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"access_type",@"approval_prompt", nil]];
```

Hope is will be usefull for someone out there! :-)

Comment: Please may you help me. I have the same problem that I don't know how to get the refresh token. So the code you have above did you add it in the "viewController finishedWithAuth" method or did you add it in some other method. Please help me. Maybe if you could share a basic sample code with me I would be very grateful. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use authenticationWithServiceProvider: when signing in to services other than Google, but for those services, do not use Google's token URL; use the service provider's token URL.

When signing in to Google, do not create an auth object; just call GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch +controllerWithScope:. If the user signs in successfully, the callback with contain the auth object.

Compare the sample app's signing in to a Google service and to a non-Google service to see the different approaches.

Comment: do you maybe know what am I doing wrong [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840977/ios-linkedin-authentication-with-gtmoauth2)?